# How to Map Array from Case class in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Sample Data** :( 251~jhon~WrappedArray([STD,Health,Duval]) )

```
case class xyz(id : String, code : String, County : String)

case class rewards(memId : String, name: String, part: Array[xyz])

val df = spark.read.textFile("file:///data/").rdd.map(r => r.split('~'))

val df2 = df.map(x => { rewards(x(0),x(1), Array[rewards.apply()] ) } )
```

tried many way to map an array from case class. tried apply function

Comment: That sample data doesn't make any sense, what format is that supposed to be in? Why does your file has a "container" Wrapper Array?

Comment: i have data in a mongo Collection as below  and i need to changed the field names in array and map them to different name 
{
Id :251,
name : Jhon,
particition : [
{
id : STD,
code: Health,
County:  Duval
}]

Comment: Why are you trying to read a Mongo database as a text file instead of connecting via a database driver?

Comment: i am not reading it as a text file. we are loading MongoCollection into DataFrame and we stored the data in HDFS, when we store the Data in HDFS that the format we have. we want to read the data and transform into different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that's what you are looking for but you can try using pattern matching to transform arrays into case classes.

```scala
val data: RDD[rewards] = sc
    .parallelize(Seq("251~jhon~WrappedArray([STD,Health,Duval])"))
    .map(_.split("~"))
    .map{ case Array(id, code, part) => (id, code, part
               .replaceFirst("\\s*WrappedArray\\(\\s*\\[\\s*", "")
               .replaceFirst("\\s*\\]\\s*\\)\\s*", "") 
    )}
    .map{ case (id, name, part) => rewards(id, name, part.split("\\s*,\\s*") match {
         case Array(id, code, county) => Array(xyz(id, code, county)) 
    })}
```